# Simulating memcache get and set race condition and solving it with add

Tags: python, multithreading, cache, locking, memcache

Memcache `get` and `set` can hit a race condition if you use them together to achieve something like locking because it is not *atomic*. A Simple `memcache` locking logic using `get` and `set` would look like:

```
def access(resource):
    if memcache.get(resource):
       return "Access Denied"
    else:
       memcache.set(resource, timestamp)
       return "Access Granted and Lock Obtained"
```

If this code is running in multi-threaded web applications, you can have a scenario where two `get` can happen together. Hence both will get the access the resource.

`add` doesn't get into this problem because it just sets the `key` only if the `key` does not exists. It also makes only a single roundtrip and hence it is *atomic* by default.

The same API with `add` would look like:

```
def access(resource):
    if memcache.add(resource, timestamp):
       return "Access Granted and Lock Obtained"
    else:
       return "Acess Denied"
```

Now, I am writing a script to simulate this race condition while using `get` , `set` and prove that using `add` solves the concurrent access problem with this naive `memcache` lock implementation. I am using files as my resource here. Multiple users can see the same file in the web application front-end and move it to another location if they get a `lock` to that file. However, sometimes `get`, `set` race condition happens giving access to the file for two users leading to `file not found` error for one of the users. Using `add` doesn't lead to this problem.

The script uses `threading` to simulate this scenario. If a `file not found` error happens then its considered a failure. I have two variants of the `move` function, one using `get`, `set` and another using `add` which can be used in the `run` method of the `thread` to demonstrate both functionalities.

Can anyone review this and tell me if this code is fine? A high level logical review is also fine if it is hard to set this up in your machine. One thing I notice is that the ratio of error is pretty high, but is this because I am actually doing `threading` which really is not random.

Pre-requisites: You need `memcache` module and `memcached` server running on port `5551` to run this. You also need a folder called `archive` to move the files.

```
import memcache
import signal
import sys
import shutil
import os
import threading
import time

mc = memcache.Client(['127.0.0.1:5551'], debug=0)
cwd = os.getcwd()
error = 0
processed = 0

def touch(fname, times=None):
    with open(fname, 'a'):
        os.utime(fname, times)

def signal_handler(signal, frame):
    print('You pressed Ctrl+C!')
    sys.exit(0)

signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, signal_handler)
print("Ctrl-C exits")

def create_files():
    for fname in range(1,11):
        touch(str(fname) + ".txt")

def move_files_get_set():
    global error
    global processed
    files = [file for file in os.listdir(".") if file.endswith(".txt")]
    for file in files:
        if os.path.isfile(file) and not mc.get(file):
            processed = processed + 1 
            mc.set(file, int(round(time.time() * 1000)))
            try:
                shutil.move(os.path.join(cwd, file), os.path.join(cwd, "archive", "%s" % file))
            except Exception as e:
                print(e)
                processed = processed - 1
                error = error + 1
                print("%s errors happened with %s" % (error, processed))
            mc.set(file, None)

def move_files_add():
    global error
    global processed
    files = [file for file in os.listdir(".") if file.endswith(".txt")]
    for file in files:
        if os.path.isfile(file) and mc.add(file, int(round(time.time() * 1000))):
            processed = processed + 1 
            try:
                shutil.move(os.path.join(cwd, file), os.path.join(cwd, "archive", "%s" % file))
            except Exception as e:
                print(e)
                processed = processed - 1
                error = error + 1
                print("%s errors happened with %s" % (error, processed))
            mc.set(file, None)

class myThread (threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, threadID, name, counter):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.threadID = threadID
        self.name = name
        self.counter = counter
    def run(self):
        print "Starting " + self.name
        move_files_get_set()
        print "Exiting " + self.name

def trigger():
    while True:
        create_files()
        t1 = myThread("1", "Thread 1", "1")
        t2 = myThread("2", "Thread 2", "2")
        t1.start()
        t2.start()
        t1.join()
        t2.join()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## You have a race condition!

But not just the one you expected. Let's take out the 'beef' of the algorithm, and make something simpler:

```
import threading

processed = 0

def move_files_get_set():
    global processed
    for val in xrange(100000):
        processed = processed + 1

class myThread (threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, threadID, name, counter):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.threadID = threadID
        self.name = name
        self.counter = counter

    def run(self):
        print "Starting " + self.name
        move_files_get_set()
        print "Exiting " + self.name

def trigger():
    t1 = myThread("1", "Thread 1", "1")
    t2 = myThread("2", "Thread 2", "2")
    t1.start()
    t2.start()
    t1.join()
    t2.join()
    print processed


if __name__ == "__main__":
    trigger()
```

What I did was basically take out everything related to memcache and files.

Here's the output:

```
$ python base.py
Starting Thread 1
Starting Thread 2
Exiting Thread 1
Exiting Thread 2
123418
$ python base.py
Starting Thread 1
Starting Thread 2
Exiting Thread 2
Exiting Thread 1
182550
```

## Another race condition

In `move_files_add`.

```
def move_files_add():
    global error
    global processed
    files = [file for file in os.listdir(".") if file.endswith(".txt")]
    for file in files:
        if os.path.isfile(file) and mc.add(file, int(round(time.time() * 1000))):
            processed = processed + 1 
            try:
                shutil.move(os.path.join(cwd, file), os.path.join(cwd, "archive", "%s" % file))
            except Exception as e:
                print(e)
                processed = processed - 1
                error = error + 1
                print("%s errors happened with %s" % (error, processed))
            mc.set(file, None)
```

What can happen is:

```
* p1: os.path.isfile(file) -> true
* p2: os.path.isfile(file) -> true
* p1: mc.add(file, bla) -> true
* p1: shutil.move() -> done
* p1: mc.set(file, None) -> done
* p2: mc.add(file, bla) -> true
* p2: shutil.move() -> KABOOM!
```

## Moving files *the correct way*

When doing files, and there is a risk of race conditions, (almost) *always* use the following pattern:

```
try:
    os.rename(source, target)
except FileNotFoundError:
    # Oops, too late!
```

Now, `os.rename` has a problem, it only works on the *same* filesystem. So depending on your needs you could do something like:

```
try:
    os.rename(source, tempfile_in_same_dir_as_source)
except FileNotFoundError:
    # Oops, too late! No worries.
    pass
else:
    # Yes, it worked. Now we just need to make sure it's moved
    # to the right target location.
    shutil.move(tempfile_in_same_dir_as_source, target)
```

Comment: Thanks for analyzing this one. `Thread` race itself can't be avoided but that is to simulate the real time scenario of users. So I need that :-) The second point is valid, I can bump into that scenario. I have enhanced the `add` function in this review question http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/131258/function-to-lock-a-file-using-memcache-version-2. Do you see any races there? Solving using try: except is easy way out, so I want to avoid try: except as a challenge. Is there a theoretical way to avoid races, is that possible etc.

Comment: I tried also looking at that one yesterday, but wemt to bed instead. Maybe I'll take a look later today. For now: why not consider compare-and-set. http://neopythonic.blogspot.nl/2011/08/compare-and-set-in-memcache.html?m=1 ? It's supposed to also be used for atomic mutations.

Comment: I took a look. But compare-and-set can be used to implement compare-and-swap, which gives you a better ability to report the key of the process doing the handling.

Comment: Read this as 3rd comment. Fixing a typo. Yeah, please have a look. I read that blog by GVR. It helped me understand race condition better but compare-and-set seemed to be for handling dirty state while doing get-set which different from my use case like say when you want to append that value to a new value etc. In my case `add` seemed to be betterv and the development team also pointed out some examples using `add`. More than data the avalibility or not of the key seemed more important.

Comment: If compare-and-set is not needed, it's not needed. I already added answer to the other question.

Comment: I will also see how `cas` can be useful probably like you said about reporting it might help.  Its a good suggestion though.