# Function to lock a file using memcache, Version 2

Tags: python, locking, memcache

Based on suggested reviews for [Function to lock a file using memcache](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/131239/function-to-lock-a-file-using-memcache), I have modified the code to

```
import os
import shutil
import memcache

def addToCart(filename, username):
    ableToLock = memcache.add(filename, username)
    if ableToLock:
        # "ableToLock" can happen if the file is still present
        # or if it was already processed.
        if os.file.ispath(filename):
            # I have a lock and file exists. Think of Cart as a
            # JS Object from where you can pick items to "process".
            return "Added To Cart"
        else:
            # I have a lock but looks like file was processed already.
            # So removing the residual "key" created.
            memcache.delete(filename)
            return "Processed by another user." 
    else:
        # "add" can also fail if remote server is down,
        # but now we are not handling that now. It will
        # block the user's ability to process anything.
        user = memcache.get(filename)
        if user and os.file.ispath(filename):
           # I try my best to show the user processing it.
           print "Being processed by %s" % user
        else:
           # But lost the race to find that.
           print "Processed by another user."


def process(source):
    shutil.move(source, destination)
    filename = os.path.basename(source)
    memcache.delete(filename)
```

Directly calling `process` is not considered valid as it can only be done from user's *Cart* and by that user. If the logic is correct, *Cart* will only have valid files at any point of time and no two *Carts* would be having the same file ever. If a request from *Cart* comes to process a filename and it doesn't exist in the file-system then it is considered flawed.

Are there any race conditions or logical flaws that still exists?

Comment: To me this code is fairly close to hypothetical code. Maybe if you show a larger example we can give a better review.

Comment: I am still on POC of this code. So it is basically the current state of the code. Based on reviews here I would finalize it and then perhaps get reviewed again.

Comment: One major flaw I can see if what if `memcache` itself is down. As their documentation says `add` can also fail if the remote server is down. So a user can never obtain a lock as opposed, in my case it blocks the productivity at the cost of stopping server errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## logical flaw

If an exception happens, your key could remain locked.

You use

```
def addToCart(filename, username):
    ableToLock = memcache.add(filename, username)
    if ableToLock:
        # ableToLock can happen if the file is still present
        # or if it was already processed.
        if os.file.ispath(filename):
            # I have a lock and file exists. Think of Cart as a
            # JS Object from where you can pick items to "process".
            return "Added To Cart"
        else:
            # I have a lock but looks like file was processed already.
            # So removing the residual "key" created.
            memcache.delete(filename)
            return "Processed by another user." 
    else:
        ...



def process(source):
    shutil.move(source, destination)
    # filename => source 
    memcache.delete(filename)
```

What if `shutil.move` throws an exception? Or `print`?

Better would be

```
if ableToLock:
    try:
        # ableToLock can happen if the file is still present
        # or if it was already processed.
        if os.file.ispath(filename):
            # I have a lock and file exists. Think of Cart as a
            # JS Object from where you can pick items to "process".
            return "Added To Cart"
        else:
            return "Processed by another user." 
    finally:
        memcache.delete(filename)
```

Comment: `print` is not there, but I got your point. If an exception happens in `shutil.move`,  I am just wondering isn't it okay if the `lock` is still held on to the file? The user can unlock it at any point. I don't see a flaw in doing that. Ofcourse removing the lock can also be done as an alternative using finally but I guess both are logical options?

Comment: I consider it as flawed if a request comes from a user to process one of his locked file and if he ever gets a `file not found` error.

Comment: Do you see any flaws other than unlocking not happening in this scenario? I would prefer to not unlock it in our workflow because it also means I need to remove it from users "Cart" in Javascript. So I am taking one step at a time. Initially just getting a working code with no race conditions.

Comment: @Nishant: I'm sorry I can't really help you with that. I think there aren't any race conditions. However, detecting race conditions by eye is really difficult, and you should not trust the judgement of a stranger on the internet for this. Also: even if this is free of race conditions, you might inadvertently add another use of locking in a sub-optimal manner and introduce a race condition.

Comment: Correct @Sjoerd, thanks for your inputs I will certainly try to simulate this. Your feedbacks are helpful, appreciate that.